# How to determine the number of the training images in Keras after data augmentaion?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, cnn, computer-vision, convolutional-neural-network

I want to create a CNN model and I am using data augmentation. I want know the number of augmented images in Keras.

How to determine the number of the training images in Keras after data augmentation?

For example, if I have 2000 images for training and I am applying data augmentation, what is the number of the images after augmentation?

Answer (score 0):

The images in the dataset are not used directly. Instead, only augmented images are provided to the model. So, your answer is 2000 images

Answer (score 0):

There are no added images generated per se, the augmented images will just be stacked on top of the original images and your batch size will still stay the same.

Answer (score -1):

You can generate as many as augmented images in Keras using ImageDataGenerator. I struggled with the same problem and figured out that there is an infinite number of images you can generate. Second thing is you can limit the number of images to be generated.

Comment: I want to know the exact number of images after data augmentation.